# ask user to get current location in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-chrome

I have a compass web app which points to the clients store location, and I want to get the users geolocation permission so I can use the two locations.

I found this code in the internet, but it doesn't work in mobile browser

```
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then(function(result) {
    /* result.status = "prompt" */
});


navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(result) { /* ... */  })

navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then(function(result) {
    /* result.status = "granted" */
});

navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'push', userVisibleOnly:true }).then(function(result) { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser must support this feature

If you browser isn't exist in this list, that's mean you can't use geolocation:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=geolocation

As we see, you need use:

- `Opera Mobile`
- `Chrome for Android`
- `Firefox for Android`
- `IE Mobile`
- `UC Browser for Android`

Comment: i'm use chrome for android and it's works fine now ,

Comment: Yes , Thank you so much